# "More than" vs. "above"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-difference

I wrote:

> To eliminate embedded advertisements or navigation links (e.g. Related articles) or irrelevant fragments (e.g. Sharing Links, Metadata, User Instructions) from the main article, the link density and the text length features were used **so that** link density *(above/more than)* 33% (as offered in [6]) was used as the indicator of boilerplate.

First I would like to know if the *...so that* clause was added correctly to the main sentence. Second, I would like to know the difference between *above* and *more than* before the percentage.

Comment: Do you want to imply **as / similar to** using **so that** ? I was unable to figure out the sentence at the first glance. Perhaps, since I expect reasons or of interest results to come after **so that**.

Comment: @Cardinal maybe **as** **in a way**... I mean I used these values in the elimination of irrelevant parts.